# Is there a way to apply multiple CSS styles in a batch to avoid multiple reflows?

Tags: javascript, dom, layout

I know that altering element's style via JavaScript directly will cause a reflow. However, I was wondering if it is possible to alter multiple style values in a batch with only one reflow?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not directly but there are some good suggestions on minimising the impact of reflows here:

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/efficient-javascript/?page=3

In short, try something like this:

> The second approach is to define a new
>   style attribute for the element,
>   instead of assigning styles one by
>   one. Most often this is suited to
>   dynamic changes such as animations,
>   where the new styles cannot be known
>   in advance. This is done using either
>   the cssText property of the style
>   object, or by using setAttribute.
>   Internet Explorer does not allow the
>   second version, and needs the first.
>   Some older browsers, including Opera
>   8, need the second approach, and do
>   not understand the first. So the easy
>   way is to check if the first version
>   is supported and use that, then fall
>   back to the second if not.

```
var posElem = document.getElementById('animation');
var newStyle = 'background: ' + newBack + ';' +
  'color: ' + newColor + ';' +
  'border: ' + newBorder + ';';
if( typeof( posElem.style.cssText ) != 'undefined' ) {
  posElem.style.cssText = newStyle; // Use += to preserve existing styles
} else {
  posElem.setAttribute('style',newStyle);
}
```

Comment: Good approach. Just beware that the first part of the `if` will override any already present inlined styles. Setting `posElem.style.cssText += newStyle` will do the trick anyways. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gleezer/Ae4XR/1/)

Comment: Actually it might be that the if statement could be ditched leaving just the `posElem.style.cssText += newStyle` (again, see updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gleezer/Ae4XR/2/)) as it does seem to work in the same way even if styles are not already there. Not sure about browser quirks in here though.

Comment: The link is now dead so I can't check but IIRC that was a compatability thing. Also, you don't _always_ want to append eg in an animation

Answer (score 5):

You could put all the styles in a CSS class

```
.foo { background:#000; color:#fff; ... }
```

and then assign it to the className property

```
// javascript
var your_node = document.getElementById('node_id');
your_node.className = 'foo'
```

That should trigger only one repaint/reflow

Comment: -1 Doesnt really answer the question, if the properties were preknown, obviously CSS class would be the way to go, however, if you are using js to calc. the values, then this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 5):

use:

```
document.getElementById('elemnt_ID').setAttribute('style','color:white; margin:5px;');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were using jQuery, it has a .css function that allows you to add multiple style at once:

$`('element').css({'color':'red', 'border':'#555 solid thin'});`

Comment: Nice thinking - I'll have to look at what that actually does behind the scenes

Answer (score 0):

You could set the element's visibility to 'hidden', then apply the styles and then make it visible again.